# Use multiple App Maker fragment forms on the same page

Tags: google-app-maker

So if I have a customer lookup fragment form (i.e. name to lookup and displays address), then need a page with a from and to customer, is there a way to isolate the data binding so that both can be individual?

Currently I can only get the same data to show up in either and so changing one effects the other.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah got it!  In part to what @Pavel responded with....
So in the fragment, the data source is set up pretty much normally:
[image: Fragment Settings]
In the inserted fragments, settings are as follows: 
 - over-ride checked
 - datasource: @Datasources.Addresses.items

[image: Page Settings]
Both fragments now act individually on selected name.

Comment: **NOTE!**  It's important that _Options_ and _Value_ are set as shown in the first image above.  ------  
Interestingly tho, **I had trouble setting them that way** _(read: wasted hours!)_ until I wiped them completely using _custom_ and tried again.  Not sure if AppMaker is buggy here or what!  Once set this way, binding works as you would expect it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can override page fragment's datasource:
[image]

Once you check 'Override page fragment datasource' checkbox, datasource property will become editable.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, but I thought I tried that.  I had the data source set up specifically in the fragment and I had inherited none on the page itself, but still both widgets display the same data.  Is there something else I need to do?